# How can I find values of $a,b,c$ when function is continuous?

Tags: limits, continuity

> Given that the function $   f\left(x\right) = \left\{
>       \begin{array}{lr}
>         ax+2 &  0 \le x \le 1\\
>         bx^2 +3ax +5 &  1<x \le 2\\
>         e^{2x} +b & 2 < x \le 3\\   
>         (cx+3)^2 +2ax & 3 < x \le 4\\   
>       \end{array}    \right.\\$ 
>  is continuous on the interval $[0,4]$. Find the values of $a,b $ and $ c$

I tried solving by equating right side limit of $1$ to the left side limit  ($ax +2$ and $bx^2 + 3ax + 5$) but got stuck with equations.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

At $x=1$, you get $a(1)+2=b(1)^2+3a(1)+5$.

Similarly, you should be able to get equations at $x=2$ and $x=3$ respectively.

Now, solve the linear system of equations.

Comment: I tried but at x = 2, I got the same equation.

Comment: at $x=2$, we get $4b+6a+5=e^4+b$ which is very different from the first equation isn't it?